# Force attribute value on potentially non-existent or locked PyNode

Tags: python, maya

I am working in Maya using [PyMEL](https://github.com/LumaPictures/pymel) (my goal is to leverage PyMEL to create more readable, object-oriented, Pythonic code than if I'd used `maya.cmds`). I need to set an attribute value on an arbitrary [node](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/JPN/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/pynodes.html). The attribute may not exist or, if it does exist, may be locked. I found that [`setAttr`](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/JPN/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/generated/functions/pymel.core.general/pymel.core.general.setAttr.html) with `force=True` did not account for all these scenarios, so I made my own.

```
import pymel.core as core

def _maya_force_attribute(self, pynode, name, value, data_type="string", keyable=False, lock=False):

    if pynode.hasAttr(name):
        pynode.setAttr(name, lock=False)
        pynode.deleteAttr(name)

    pynode.addAttr(name, dataType=data_type)
    pynode.setAttr(name, value, keyable=keyable, lock=lock)
```

What I discovered (I think) is that when using `set`/`add`/`deleteAttr`, you can't often use multiple flags at the same time.

Is there a command sequence or a command/flag combo that achieves the same result more directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation link](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/JPN/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/generated/functions/pymel.core.general/pymel.core.general.setAttr.html) you provided:

> ‘force’ kwarg, which causes the attribute to be added if it does not exist.

So the `force` kwargs does not seem to allow you to set a new `dataType`.

Hence it seems that the only way to set a new `dataType` is to remove and recreate the attribute. From this case, it seems hard to further simplify your code.

Comment: if, for the sake of argument, I could rely on the type being correct, would that change anything?

Comment: It depends on the `lock` behavior: can you do `setAttr` if the attribute is locked ?

Comment: nope (so I discovered) -- so it sounds like, based on my attempts and your feedback (and documentation highlighting :D ) there is no "built-in" way to do this -- thanks for the review!